# Slow performance of establishing cx-oracle Connection pool in FLASK Application

Tags: python, oracle, flask, connection-pooling

i have a question regarding the Connection pooling in my Flask APP. Queries work fast but the initial establishing of Databaseconnection takes more than 40 seconds.

I have 2 Connections that are being opened in the code below, each of them takes 20 seconds

class DBconnection:
connections = None
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)

```
def __init__(self):
    logging.debug('creating pool connection for pool1')
    t1 = time.time()

    self.connections = {}

    pool1 = cx_Oracle.SessionPool(user='                                           password='a#####',
                                       dsn="(######))",
                                       min=1,
                                       max=2,
                                       increment=0,
                                       threaded=True,
                                       timeout=0,
                                       wait_timeout=10,
                                       getmode=cx_Oracle.SPOOL_ATTRVAL_WAIT,
                                       sessionCallback=None)


    t2 = time.time()

    logging.debug(colorama.Fore.GREEN + '#### Connection established successfully in {}s'.format(
        round(time.time() - t1, 2)) + colorama.Style.RESET_ALL)

    self.connections["####"] = #####

    pool2 = cx_Oracle.SessionPool(user='asdass',
                                        password='#####',
                                        dsn="#####",
                                        min=1,
                                        max=2,
                                        increment=0,
                                        threaded=True,
                                        timeout=0,
                                        wait_timeout=10,
                                        getmode=cx_Oracle.SPOOL_ATTRVAL_WAIT,
                                        sessionCallback=None)

    logging.debug(colorama.Fore.GREEN + '#### Connection established successfully in {}s'.format(
        round(time.time() - t2, 2)) + colorama.Style.RESET_ALL)
    self.connections["####"] = ######

def __enter__(self):
    return self

def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
    logging.debug("Closing connections")
    if self.connections["###"] is not None:
        logging.debug("closing  connection")
        self.connections["force"].close()

    if self.connections["###"] is not None:
        logging.debug("closing ### connection")
        self.connections["e####sidwh"].close()
```

Comment: Update your question with the format of your dsn - is it an easy connect string, connect alias or connect descriptor? Do you have a sqlnet.ora file with a NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH entry? Is your DNS behaving itself? Update the question with versions of cx_Oracle, Oracle Client libraries & DB. Do you have something (e.g. an oraacess.xml file, or service setting) that is enabling ONS. If this can't start properly there may be a connection delay.

Comment: Thank you for your Response Christoph, in that matter i lack information a litte, because it is all set up by my Company. But it is not Easy Connect, it is TNS, there is a sqlnet.ora file in the Directory , but I think Iám accessing it directly and I have the latest Version of CX-Oracle installed. Also the establishing Duration strongly depends on the Poolsize, for example 4 Connections take like several Minutes .

Comment: Test connecting with another tool such as SQL*Plus.  Try pinging to check the network speed. Share what's in sqlnet.ora.   (PS The latest version of cx_Oracle is called python-oracledb so you could upgrade! See the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a))

Comment: New Module worked really well. It now connects immediately! But the session pool wasnt working, the create_pool did. Thank you a lot Sir !